# Simulating SQL Connections in R

Tags: sql, r

I am trying to learn if there is a way to "simulate" an SQL connection within R that lets me test Netezza SQL.

I know how to do this with an "SQLite" connection - here, I am making a temporary connection "on the spot":

```
library(DBI)   
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")  
dbWriteTable(con, "iris", iris) 

DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select a.* from (select *, row_number() over (order by `Petal.Length`) as rnum from iris) a  limit 5;")
```

But is it possible to make such an "on the spot" connection with a Netezza SQL connection? In other words - could I try replacing the SQL code in this question with NETEZZA specific SQL functions (e.g. TO_CHAR)?

Thanks!

Note: If this does not work - is there some other way to create datasets and test NETEZZA SQL queries on them in some simulated/test environment?

Comment: I don't understand the *simulating SQL connection* need. Can you not connect to Netezza? R supports ODBC which is a generialized technology for any data source with such a driver including SQLite! Why not write a Netezza compliant SQL and run it in `dbGetQuery`?

Comment: When I am at home, I like to learn and practice running SQL queries ... I am on my home computer and dont have anywere to practice/learn. This is why I thought I could simulate a SQL connection within R for educational purposes

Comment: Well I know DB2 has a free version, maybe Netezza? O/W use DB2 which may share similar SQL dialect like `TO_CHAR`. But recommendation of software is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: make your own sqlite databse to practise or use one of the dbfddle for it

Comment: Netezza was originally based on Postgresql-7.2 (okay, a long time ago); while it has since broken compatibility, it's possible that you can use `sqldf` with a postgres engine to perhaps be somewhat close for your practicing needs. By default sqldf will use the sqlite engine, see FAQ 12 of the sqldf https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf#12-how-does-one-use-sqldf-with-postgresql. Another option would be to use the duckdb package, which is based very closely (again) on postgres.